# atoi behaving eratically while reading a date from file

Tags: c

I have been struggling with this problem of atoi function since yesterday evening, but no escapes. I created a program where two functions are: 1- Find the no. of days since OS got updated. 2- Find the no. days since Antivirus got updated.
Now after a lot of looping I found out the two dates in mm/dd/yy format and wrote in a file. Presently I am working on only Antivirus date (which I got after converting a hex value to decimal) and stored it in a new file. For example take the date as: 07/17/2013. Only this date is written in the file. The hex data in the file (after opening file through hex workshop) is:

```
    HEX VALUE --------------------------DECIMAL VALUE
    37 2F 31 37 2F 32 30 31 33 0D 0A --- 7/17/2013..
```

Now I run 3 loops so that I get 7, 17, 2013 in separate char variables. But when I convert these into decimal using atoi, 7 & 17 becomes 0 but 2013 remains 2013. I have completed rest of the 90% project & stuck up at this last piece.
   The file's character encoding can't be changed because I have to implement the whole program on domain machines,& I don't find any way to work with UTFs. After converting individual day,month,year into integer value, I have to find a date's toatl value and compare it with current date & find the difference. So, plz provide some solution.

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp_av_dt;
    int ch_av,n=0,n1=0,n2=0,i=0,iday1=0,imon1=0,iyr1=0;
    int mon_val1=0,arr_days_values_av=0;   
    char dt_av[11],amon1[3],aday1[3],ayr1[5];

    fp_av_dt=fopen("c:\\windows\\web\\wallpaper\\av_dt.txt","r");

    while((ch_av=fgetc(fp_av_dt))!='\n')
    {
        if(isalnum(ch_av) | ch_av=='/' | ch_av=='\n')
        /* leave any other char other than '/','\n' or any digit */
        {
            dt_av[n]=ch_av;
            //printf("%c",dt_av[n]); 
            //store chars in dt_av array
            n++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(n=0;dt_av[n]!='/';n++)       /* Loop & wait till '/' comes */
    {
        amon1[i]=dt_av[n];     /* store elements in month's array */   
        //printf("%c",amon1[i]);
        i++;     
    }

    i=0;

    for(n1=(n+1);dt_av[n1]!='/';n1++)   /*Loop & wait till next '/' comes */
    {
        aday1[i]=dt_av[n1];   store elements in day's array */
        //printf("%c",aday1[i]);
        i++;    
    }

    i=0;

    for(n2=(n1+1);dt_av[n2]!='\n';n2++)
    {
        ayr1[i]=dt_av[n2];    store elements in year's array */
        //printf("%c",ayr1[i]);
        i++;     
    }

    i=0;

    iday1=atoi(aday1);        /* convert array to integer */       
    printf("%d\n",iday1);

    imon1=atoi(amon1);                   
    printf("%d\n",imon1);  

    iyr1=atoi(ayr1);                     
    printf("%d\n",iyr1);

    system("PAUSE");
}   /* Uncomment printf lines to see the value of any variable */
```

It is bedtime here. So will come online after 10 hrs. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `for` loop with

```
fscanf(fp_av_dt, "%d/%d/%d", &iday1, &imon1, &iyr1);
```

The return should be 3 indicating 3 values have been read.

c.f. [scanf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's "behaving erratically" is because none of your `char` arrays are NUL terminated. Changing:

```
i=0;
```

to:

```
amon[i] = '\0'; i = 0;
```

and the like should fix it, although you still won't have any bounds-checking.

Answer (score 1):

normally keeping things simple is better so why don't first read the line

```
char buffer[16];
fgets( buffer, 16, fp );
```

then extract the contents using

```
int month = 0, day = 0, year = 0;
int args = sscanf( buffer, "%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year );
if ( args != 3 ) 
{
  fprintf(stderr, "wrong format\n" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the solutions and giving me some scanf commands. I found the way out. It is very strange but worked.
when I converted the value of each char variable to integer just after finishing its assignment, it gives correct value. Whereas till now I was converting(atoi) all the variables all together(i.e.- after storing elements in all the arrays). Solution for example:

```
    for(n=0;dt_av[n]!='/';n++)     /* wait till '/' comes */
    {
        amon1[i]=dt_av[n]; //assign 7 to amon (month) variable                    
        i++;     
    }  
    amon1[i+1]='\0'; /* didn't actually make any difference, but still it should be kepy */
    i=0;   imon1=atoi(amon1);
    printf("%d\n",imon1);
```

I couldn't understand why this is happening & kept me in spin for last 24 hours. Anyways, thanks to all.

Comment: This is still wrong. At this point, you should do `amon1[i]='\0'`, not `amon1[i+1]='\0'`. Also, you may wish to consider using `strtol()` instead of `atoi()`.